# Project Versioning in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, project

The book [Spring in Action 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294942) comes with some downloadable source code, which is organized by chapters.  I am trying to load the software in NetBeans [Maven -> Spring Boot Initializr project].  The link for the downloadable software is as follows:
https://www.manning.com/downloads/1599

The problem that I am facing is that the project name, across multiple chapter POM files, is the same.  However, the project version (as specified in the chapter POM files) varies from chapter to chapter.  What is the best way to organize the source code in NetBeans?

I don't know of any option for specifying the version number for a NetBeans project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical issue with having multiple projects with the same name open in NetBeans concurrently. While that is generally not a good idea, for what you are doing it's appropriate. So to load all instances of that project in its multiple states into NetBeans:

- Download the zip file to some arbitrary directory, and create a directory to contain the unzipped projects.
- Select **File > Import Project > From ZIP...**
- In the **Import Project(s) from ZIP** screen, click **Browse...** to locate the downloaded **ZIP file**, and the target **Folder** to contain all the projects, then click **Import**.

When the import is complete you should see a file structure similar to this in your file explorer:

[image: fileStructureOnDisk]

You will also see a lot of new projects in the **Projects** panel in NetBeans:

[image: projectStructureInNetBeans]

I assume that **taco-cloud** is the project you are developing, chapter by chapter. While it is potentially confusing to have multiple projects open at the same time with the same name, you can easily identify any project by selecting it and waiting for a tooltip to display a summary of the project.

For example, the screen shot below shows that the selected project is for chapter 5 of the book:

[image: projectTooltip]

To reduce confusion, you may find it convenient to also close some or all of the **taco-cloud** project instances that you are not working on, and open/close them as you progress through the chapters in the book.

One other related point: there are a couple of *Unresolved project problem...* messages in the tooltip. To fix those, select the **taco-cloud** project node, right click and select **Resolve Project Problems...** from the context menu.